# Background position center and 1900px at the same time

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello I'm trying to make a rullete game and I have a problem with my background image. I want to change its position and make it center at the same time.

```css
body {
  background-image: url(rulette.png);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-position: 1900px center;
}
```

```html
<body>body</body>
```

This doesn't so I tried to make that in two rows instead like this:

```
background-image: url(rulette.png);
background-repeat: repeat-x;
background-position: 1900px;
background-position: center;
```

What happens is that the pixel position is working just fine but the position center doesn't work. So I tried to change the position like this:

```
background-image: url(rulette.png);
background-repeat: repeat-x;
background-position: 1900px;
background-position: center;
```

Now the center position work just fine but it skips the pixel position.
Am I trying to do something impossible? I really need to make it work. Do you have any Idea how I can change the backgrounds pixel position and center the image. Note that the background is repeatable.

When I'm resizing the browser window the background is moving. I want it to stay in the same position.

Comment: [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position) may help you decide what to do

Comment: What about `background-position: center 1900px;`?

Comment: Put up an verifiable example that exhibits the issue with the HTML, that will help us help you https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: "When I'm resizeing the browserwindow the background is moving" - so, WHAT do you wish to center on? By definition, `center` will move when you resize if that is on the full page body.  Please clarify your intent.  Adding a complete verifiable example with the HTML and all CSS that exhibits your issue will certainly help here.

Answer (score 1):

The background position is filled first with the **X axis** and **Y axis** last.
You should try something like:

```
background-position: 50% 1900px;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should type like following:

```
background-position: 1900px center;
```

Because your code `background-position: 1900px;` and `background-position: center;` is just applying only one value at a time and overriding one by another.

Answer (score 0):

Since some ambiguity in your question exists, I am going to just take a wild stab at what my current interpretation of that is, give it and x position and center with a 100% size.  Simply my guess so you get what you get.

```css
body {
  background-size: 100%;
  background-image: url("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/46/Jennifer_Lawrence_at_the_83rd_Academy_Awards.jpg");
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-position-x: 1900px;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<body>body</body>
```